# Unable to make request to GitLab API using the Node.js

Tags: node.js, https, axios, request

I am trying to read the data from GitLab using the GitLab API. The API works correctly because when I tried directly in Chrome browser I got the `JSON` response as well as in `Postman`.

If I try to make the request to the same URL using Node.js then I do not get any response or error. I am not understanding what's the issue. I tried making requests using the following approaches: `request`, `HTTPS`, and `Axios` but none of them are working nor giving errors.

Following is the code same that I have from Node.js:

`./index.js`

```
const   express     =   require('express');
const   http        =   require("http");
const   bodyParser  =   require('body-parser');
const   app         =   express();
const   port        =   process.env.PORT || 9000;
const   gitlabDump  =   require("./controller/GitLabDump");

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Make NodeJS to Listen to a particular Port in Localhost
app.listen(port, function(){
    var project = "gitlab";

    if(project.trim() === "gitlab"){
        //If porject is GitLab then fetch the data from Gitlab
        console.log("Fetching GitLab Data.......");

        gitlabDump.gitlabDump(type, function(data){
            console.log("Completed Execution for GitLab")
            process.exit();
        })
    }
}
```

My `./controller/GitLabDump.js`:

```
const request = require('request');
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios');

exports.gitlabDump = function(callback){
    var gitlabAPI = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/tree?ref=<target_branch>&path=path/to/subdirectory";

    console.log("BEFORE \n")

    request(gitlabAPI, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log("WITHIN RESPONSE")  
    })


    https.get(gitlabAPI, res => {
      console.log('Status Code:', res.statusCode);
      console.log('Date in Response header:', res);
    }).on('error', err => {
      console.log('Error: ', err.message);
    });

    axios.get(gitlabAPI).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err.message);
    });

    console.log("AFTER \n")

    callback("Completed");
}
```

I run the application from my command line:

```
node index.js
```

I get the response:

```
BEFORE 

AFTER 

Completed
```

Meaning it's not going into any of the requests and not getting any error as well. Still stuck on this issue. Any assistance would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I copied  the the code, execute it and it worked fine... can you show us how are you calling the function... ?

Comment: @clay Thanks a lot for the response. I have added the complete code, can you please have a look and let me know if I am missing something? The code you tried works fine with all approaches `https, axios, request` or just some specific approach? I have done other API calls using `request` and they work well not sure whats wrong with this `Gitlab API` within `Nodejs`.

Comment: @clay Do you think it has to do something with the permission? Because I am able to open in Chrome and Postman so not sure if it's related to permission. If it was permission then shouldn't I get some sort of warning? Just wanted to confirm all possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are using `process.exit()` and this function ends the program as you can see [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-exit-from-a-nodejs-program)

**The solutions:** delete `process.exit()`

Javascript is asynchronous, when you read a file or when you send a http request these operations take a while... meanwhile javascript execute all the code bellow the functions... So if you kill the program with `process.exit()`,  you are not waiting for the end of the functions...

If you want the script ends and the terminal exits from node you don't need to use express, just create a file as follows and execute directly with node:

```
const request = require('request');
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios');

const gitlabDump = function(callback){
    var gitlabAPI = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/tree?ref=<target_branch>&path=path/to/subdirectory";

    console.log("BEFORE \n")

    request(gitlabAPI, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log("WITHIN RESPONSE")  
    })


    https.get(gitlabAPI, res => {
      console.log('Status Code:', res.statusCode);
      console.log('Date in Response header:', res);
    }).on('error', err => {
      console.log('Error: ', err.message);
    });

    axios.get(gitlabAPI).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err.message);
    });

    console.log("AFTER \n")

    callback("Completed");
}

gitlabDump(function(data){
    console.log("Completed Execution for GitLab")
})
```

execute the next command in a shell (bash, cmd or  powershell)

```
  node filename.js
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This works fine for me. Actually, the problem was I was giving the `callback` before giving the time to make the request. Thanks a lot again for the response.